# In app subscription purchase over 3G says wifi must be available?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm working on an iOS app that uses in app subscriptions and one of the testers has reported that when trying to buy a subscription over 3G they get a message that reads:

"Wifi Required. This item can only be downloaded over a wifi connection."

Anyone seen this before? It makes no sense that users can't subscribe over 3G. It's just a receipt that gets returned, not megabytes of data.

Answer (score 2):

If your testers use iOS 5 beta they can try **Settings > Store > Use Cellular Data [ON]**
and plz remember that iOS 5 beta still under NDA :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've checked and the testers are not on iOS 5 beta.